# Visual Studio 2015 web compiler not back-tracing errors

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sass, web-essentials, web-compiler

I'm compiling a file manifest scss file called Site.scss which @import's a list of partial .scss files. I'm using Web Essentials and Web Compiler. Sometimes, if there is a compile error in one of the partials it doesnt backtrace to the line of the error. It just says the error is in Site.scss
In the past i would just manually compile each partial to trace it when this happens, but with this current project there are over 50. I would like to know if there is way to fix this.
in Site.scss i have something like this:

```
@import "settings.config";
@import "tools.functions";
@import "components.popup";
@import "components.modal";
...
```

So if there is an error in tools.functions, it won't trace the error to that file. **See screenshot**.

[image]